# :( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "plaintext: a\..."

Tags: c, return, command-line-arguments, cs50, caesar-cipher

I completed writing a Cypher code, but when I compile and run on the cs50 ide it works well without any errors but when I use check50, it throws up some errors which are making me confused. Turly appreciate any help.
Here are my errors:

```
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
    expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "plaintext:  a\..."
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "plaintext:  wo..."
```

This is the code that I've written:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int index[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
    string str;
    string plaintext;
    int n;
    char cyphertext[100];
    int key;



    if (argc == 2)
    {
        str = argv[1];

        for(int i = 0;i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(str[i]))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }

   if(argc == 2)
   {

       key = atoi(str);                 //convert string to int
       plaintext = get_string("Text: ");    // get plain text
       for(int i = 0; i<strlen(plaintext); i++)
       {
           if(isupper(plaintext[i]))
           {
               n = 0;
               n = index[plaintext[i] - 'A'];
               cyphertext[i] = ((n + key) % 26) + 'A' ;
           }
           else if(islower(plaintext[i]))
           {
               n = 0;
               n = index[plaintext[i] - 'a'];
               cyphertext[i] = ((n + key) % 26 ) + 'a';

           }
           else
           {
               cyphertext[i] = plaintext[i];

           }
       }

      printf("plaintext:  %s\n",plaintext);
      printf("ciphertext: %s\n",cyphertext);
      
   }
   

return 1;
}
```

It says expected exit code 0, not 1 , when I return 0 it says:

```
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "plaintext:  wo..."
:( handles lack of argv[1]
    expected exit code 1, not 0
```

Comment: Adding `return 0;` after printing the results should fix the one error.

Comment: yes! I tried that. It says 
:( handles lack of argv[1]
    expected exit code 1, not 0

Comment: Did you put `return 0` right after `printf("ciphertext: %s\n",cyphertext);` ? Leaving the final `return 1;`?

Comment: I fixed the errors with the return values 0 and 1 by removing the additional if statement on line 25 but now I am getting these two errors.
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
    expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "plaintext:  a\..."
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "plaintext:  wo..."

Comment: Don't forget to null terminate: `cyphertext[strlen(plaintext)] = '\0';`

Answer (score -1):

val = encode( cipher_text )

give space on both sides of the "cipher_text"

this is just an example

donot use like this
val = encode( cipher_text)
or this
val = encode(cipher_text )

Comment: The C compiler doesn't care about the spacing in function calls. So this makes absolutely no difference.,